# Find variance of a random variable depending from two other ones

Tags: mathematical-statistics, variance, random-variable, covariance-matrix

I got an algorithm from which i am estimating an unit vector  : $$[X,Y,Z]$$
This vector is deterministic and has the following properties :

$$X \in\quad [0,1]$$$$ Y\in\quad[0,1]$$$$  Z\in\quad[0,1]$$
$$X^2+Y^2+Z^2 = 1$$

I don't have access to this vector but only on estimations $\widehat{X}$ and $\widehat{Y}$ (and associated covariance matrix) that I'm finding through measurements. I am interested in finding an estimator of Z and a natural one for me is :
$$\widehat{Z}= \sqrt{1-\widehat{X}^2-\widehat{Y}^2}\ $$

If i make the following assumptions :

$\widehat{X} \hookrightarrow  \mathcal{N}(X,\,\sigma_\widehat{X}^{2})$  and   $\widehat{Y} \hookrightarrow  \mathcal{N}(Y,\,\sigma_\widehat{Y}^{2})$

**Is it possible to derive the variance of $\widehat{Z}$ knowing X, $\sigma_\widehat{X}$, Y and $\sigma_\widehat{Y}$ ?**

I'm stuck at :

$Var(\widehat{Z}) =1-E(\widehat{X}^2)-E(\widehat{Y}^2)-E(\sqrt{1-\widehat{X}^2-\widehat{Y}^2})^2$
$Var(\widehat{Z}) =1-Var(\widehat{X})-X-Var(\widehat{Y})-Y-E(\sqrt{1-\widehat{X}^2-\widehat{Y}^2})^2$

I'm not sure how to handle the last term since X and Y are not necessarily close to 0 so I cant neither use any Taylor approximation trick nor $E(\sqrt{a}) \leqslant \sqrt{E(a)}$ for any random variable a.

Am I forced to derivate underlying integrals from this point ?

I hope that the problem statement is correct.

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What exactly do you mean X in [0,1]? X is a gaussian RV...it could be any value in [inf,inf]

Comment: $Z$ is not well defined because $X,Y$ are not well defined. Also, inside of the square root may be smaller than $0$.

Comment: Unfortunately, that contradicts your assumptions that $X$ and $Y$ have normal distributions--and that contradiction makes it impossible to answer your question.